# Ignoring exceptions vs throwing it explicitly

Tags: c#, exception

Is it alright to return an `empty object` in case of an `exception` or should we throw the `exception` so that `caller` may know what has gone wrong?

```
public async Task<UserInfoModel> GetUserInfoByRole(Role role)
    {
        UserModel userInfo = new UserModel();
        try
        {
             // do something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do logging    
            // throw;  
        }

          return userInfo;
    }
```

Comment: The caller is likely in a better position to decide if proceeding with an empty model is the correct thing to do when faced with an exception.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't impose an empty object on the caller, throw the exception imo.   You might also want to take a look at the `Maybe<>` type or `Option<>` type and see if you like the way it works.  You'll have to find a library as it's not included in c#'s standard library.

Comment: You should only throw exceptions on exceptional situations. If something is wrong, an exception tells more than an empty object.

Comment: I suggest reading this excellent article on the four categories of exceptions, by Eric Lippert: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are creating a class, component, ... for others to use, you obviously should throw an exception. because they need to know about it and handle the exception the way that suits them.

If it is a method in your own code, may be returning a null value would be sufficient, because you might just check the return value and if it is null you know that there was an error and you don't want to program break because of the exception, otherwise you will need another exception handling again.